# Magento2: Can we add range slider on product attribute

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, price, layered-navigation, filter

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In current magento2 provide range slider on product attribute "price". I have requirement range slider on Case Diameter.

[image: this image of price slider I want this type of slider on Case Diameter.]

Comment: Add more details about your question.

Comment: i add one more picture in my ques. as you can in price filter option we have range slider i want same range slider in upper option case-diameter

Comment: @AmitSaini give ans i added more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not available in Magento by default. The slider filter only works with the price attribute. For this, you need to use an external `layered navigation` extension. You can use the below 2 extensions that support this feature:
**Free Extension**: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite
**Paid Extension**: https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation-for-magento-2.html

> Note: Please read the user guide or documentation of these extensions
> before use.

Comment: Thanks @Amit Saini

Comment: Welcome @SAURABHGARG, Feel free to accept this answer if it looks useful for you.